# VB.NET cant recognize hashed bcrypt from PHP, but PHP can recognize hashed bcrypt form VB.NET

Tags: php, vb.net, bcrypt, password-hash

I used the bcrypt to hash my password. The problem is that when the password was hashed from PHP (example: `$2y$10$qLubKu5BTO7eFk8oXjk3xOZDxxQI/F0GgdgjKkL3kzF/8M565hJpq`) VB.NET cannot recognize it. But if the password was hashed using VB.NET (example: `$2a$10$XwkBsps2z3tlLU2qwumC6OjTPhg/zvudNS5g5hant9xFKxUeNupca`) PHP recognizes it. Is this some kind of version error? There is an exception: 'Invalid Salt Revision'

Thanks!

Tried different packages from nuget still at no luck :(

```vb
Dim check As String = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(txtbox_pword.Text)
If BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(txtbox_pword.Text, pword) = True Then
 'in
End If
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvXzU.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solve! Used some function to make the hash from PHP to start with $2a$ then viola! :D Thanks!